# Is the Shapely value of this voting game in the core?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Given a voting game where $v(1),v(2),v(3) = 0, v(1,2)= \frac{1} {3}, v(2,3) = \frac{5} {6}$,  $v(1,3)= \frac{1} {6}$ and $v(1,2,3) = 1$

I know the Shapely coefficients for a 3 player game, for $|s|=1, |s|=3$, the Shapely coefficient is $\frac{1} {3}$, for $|s|=2, \frac{1} {6}$. Now I calculate the Shapely values thus:

$SH_1 = \frac{1} {3} [0] + \frac{1} {6} [\frac{1}{3}-0]+\frac{1} {6} [\frac{1}{6}-0]+\frac{1} {3} [1 - \frac{5}{6}] = \frac{5}{36}$

$SH_2 = \frac{1} {3} [0] + \frac{1} {6} [\frac{1}{3}-0]+\frac{1} {6} [\frac{5}{6}-0]+\frac{1} {3} [1 - \frac{1}{6}] = \frac{17}{36}$

$SH_3 = \frac{1} {3} [0] + \frac{1} {6} [\frac{1}{6}-0]+\frac{1} {6} [\frac{5}{6}-0]+\frac{1} {3} [1 - \frac{1}{3}] = \frac{14}{36}$

And I note that $SH_1 + SH_2 + SH_3 = 1$.

Now, what are the conditions for it to be in the core? 
$SH_1 > 0, SH_2 > 0, SH_3 > 0$ is one condition, I think.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, the most useful definition of the core is that an allocation is in the core if it is efficient and coalitionally rational (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%28game_theory%29#Properties)). You've already noted that the allocation according to the Shapley values is efficient. It is clearly also coalitionally rational with respect to the empty coalition, all single-player coalitions and the grand coalition. So you just have to check that it's coalitionally rational with respect to the three two-player coalitions. This is indeed the case, since $v(1,2)\lt1-\textsf{SH}_3$, $v(2,3)\lt1-\textsf{SH}_1$ and $v(3,1)\lt1-\textsf{SH}_2$. Thus the allocation according to the Shapley values is in the core.